# jpql query manytomany

Tags: playframework, jpql

software <-m:n-> tag

I want to create query for selecting all softwares where tag.id = id

I write:

```
TypedQuery query =
              Software.em().createQuery(
               "SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Software s INNER JOIN s.tags WHERE s.tags.id = :tagId",
               Software.class
              );
              query.setParameter("tagId", tagId);
```

as result i have:

> A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   has been caught,
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal
>   attempt to dereference collection
>   [software0_.id.tags] with element
>   property reference [id] [SELECT
>   DISTINCT s FROM models.Software s
>   INNER JOIN s.tags WHERE s.tags.id =
>   :tagId]

How could I implement it? and why I have such exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you are missing the FROM clause in your statement.
The error "Unexpected token: INNER" is given because it expects a FROM.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Software s INNER JOIN s.tags t WHERE t.id = :tagId
```

Comment: i fixed. maybe, but when i put FROM i got: A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException has been caught, org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [software0_.id.tags] with element property reference [id] [SELECT DISTINCT s FROM models.Software s INNER JOIN s.tags WHERE s.tags.id = :tagId]

Comment: Try this: `SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Software s INNER JOIN s.tags t WHERE t.id = :tagId`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with:

```
Query q = JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Software s join fetch s.tags t WHERE t.id = :tagId");
q.setParameter("tagId", tagId);
```

This should work.